# Accessing the same part of the store in different components in React and Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I'm currently building an application using React and Redux. In two separate parts of the application, I want to access a list of libraries from my store. One would take all the libraries and display them as cards as the main content of a page. The other would display the libraries as a small dropdown list within a certain part of the page.

My ideas so far for implementation were to either use a higher order component that listens to the store for libraries and use it in two different presentational components, or have a single presentational component that takes in styles as a prop from the containers.

Comment: Well, if they require the exact same props, you could just have two presentational (dumb?) component wrapped in two different "container" (smart?) component which are using the exact same mapStateProps function.

Answer (score 0):

> My ideas so far for implementation were to either use a higher order component that listens to the store for libraries and use it in two different presentational components, or have a single presentational component that takes in styles as a prop from the containers.

Neither of these sound like ideal solutions. The beauty of using React with Redux is that it separates your presentation from your data. There's no reason why you can't have both components [connected](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) to the store. Indeed, this is [encouraged](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/668585589609005056).

For example:

```
// LibrariesCards.jsx
export default connect((state) => ({
  libraries: state.libraries
}))(LibrariesCards);

// LibrariesDropdown.jsx
export default connect((state) => ({
  libraries: state.libraries
}))(LibrariesDropdown);
```